# How do I optimize this SharePoint query for Terms?

Tags: c#, linq, sharepoint, caml, csom

I have a Managed Metadata Service which has a Term Group with a Term Set and Terms.

I am new to SharePoint querying and I am currently doing the following:

1. Get client context
2. Set credentials
3. Update client context cache
4. Get taxonomy session
5. Get term store
6. Get term set
7. Get terms

For every one of the above steps, I am loading and executing a query on the client context.

1. Is there a better way to load and execute queries?
2. Is there a direct LINQ query or CAML query that I can use to get the terms I need given the UID of the term set?

**Code:**

```
var siteUrl = ConfigHelper.GetValue("SharepointSiteUrl");
var clientContext = new ClientContext(siteUrl);

clientContext.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(ConfigHelper.GetValue("ServiceAccountLogonName"), ConfigHelper.GetValue("ServiceAccountPassword"));

var taxonomySession = TaxonomySession.GetTaxonomySession(clientContext);

taxonomySession.UpdateCache();

clientContext.Load(taxonomySession, ts => ts.TermStores);
clientContext.ExecuteQuery();

if (taxonomySession.TermStores.Count == 0)
{
    throw new InvalidOperationException("The Taxonomy Service is offline or missing");
}

var termStore = taxonomySession.TermStores[1];

clientContext.Load(termStore);
clientContext.ExecuteQuery();

var termSet = termStore.GetTermSet(new Guid("f40eeb54-7c87-409d-96c7-75ceed6bff60"));
clientContext.Load(termSet);
clientContext.ExecuteQuery();

var terms = termSet.GetAllTerms();
clientContext.Load(terms);
clientContext.ExecuteQuery();

foreach (var term in terms)
{
    clientContext.Load(term, t => t.Id, t => t.Name);
    clientContext.ExecuteQuery();                
}
```

How do I optimize this SharePoint query for Terms?

Comment: Could you show us your code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The main issue with specified example that a bunch of *intermediate requests are submitted to the server*, so the main optimization would be:

- eliminate those intermediate requests (see the modified example below )
- or since SharePoint CSOM supports [Request Batching](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff798420.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) *multiple client
  object could be requested from the server using a single batch
  request only*

Since if your goal is to retrieve terms *only* for a specif term set, then example could be optimized as demonstrated below:

```
var taxonomySession = TaxonomySession.GetTaxonomySession(ctx);
var termStore = taxonomySession.GetDefaultSiteCollectionTermStore();
var termSet = termStore.GetTermSet(termSetId);
var terms = termSet.GetAllTerms();
ctx.Load(terms, tcol => tcol.Include(t => t.Id,t => t.Name));
ctx.ExecuteQuery();
```

**Some recommendations**

- Prefer `TermStoreCollection.GetByName` or
  `TermStoreCollection.GetById` methods over getting TermStore by index
  since in the later case `TermStoreCollection` have to be initialized
  first
- use `TaxonomySession.GetDefaultSiteCollectionTermStore method` if you
  need to get the default Term Store

Answer (score 2):

this way

```
var taxonomySession = TaxonomySession.GetTaxonomySession(ctx);
taxonomySession.UpdateCache();
TermStore ts = taxonomySession.TermStores.GetById(termStoreId);
TermSet set = ts.GetTermSet(termSetId);
TermCollection terms = set.GetAllTerms();

ctx.Load(terms, t=>t.IncludeWithDefaultProperties(term=>term.Name, term=>term.Id));
ctx.ExecuteQuery();
```

Comment: to get child terms `Context.Load(termCollection, t => t.IncludeWithDefaultProperties(f => f.Terms));`